# Coordinates of polymer element <paper-dialog> cannot be set

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

When using the dart polymer element  of paper-elements (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements), the dialog appears in the middle of the browser. The coordinates of the dialog cannot be set and it is not possible to move it.

Are there any plans to enhance the element with that features?

Answer (score 1):

Create a feature request here https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dialog